Gradle tasks don’t show up in VS Code's Gradle plugin
A question for the VS Code wizards:
I have a Gradle project where I run main methods  from various class files from the command line. My build.gradle file (under the project root) looks like this:
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
}

java {
    toolchain ...
}

application {
    // Define a dummy main class because we run main classes in various source files
    mainClass = '....console.DontUsePlainRun'
}

tasks.register("run-ToolA", JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs = ...
    group = ApplicationPlugin.APPLICATION_GROUP
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    mainClass = '....ToolA'
}

tasks.register("run-ToolB", JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs = ...
    group = ApplicationPlugin.APPLICATION_GROUP
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    mainClass = '....ToolB'
}

...

I run the main methods of the tool classes on the command line like this:
$ gradle run-ToolA

$ gradle run-ToolB

...

This works perfectly!
However, for debugging I would like to run thee classes in VS Code via the Gradle for Java plugin. I have installed it and VS Code seems to pick up that my project is a Gradle one, but when I look at the Gradle Projects panel my run tasks don't show up:

How can I make my run tasks show up and then debug them in VS Code?

I recently had the same problem in an existing project. Suddenly the gradle tasks were no longer available on the Gradle Projects menu in VS Code. I wasn't able to get the tasks to display but I was able to run my fatJar task by opening a cmd terminal in VSCode and using the following command:
gradlew fatJar

I'm using Visual Studio Code Version 1.92.0.
My build.gradle contains task:
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveFileName = "${project.name}.jar"
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

I hope this helps.
